# Ayuda con javascript

Tags: javascript, css

no soy experto en javascript, por lo que necesito cierta ayuda para conseguir lo que busco.  Necesito la siguiente secuencia:

1.- Input no activo, solo muestra el icono fa y el texto del placeholder
2.- Input activo (focus, blur, etc), cambia color del fa, se muestra el texto del span con el color del fa.
3.- Al moverme a otro input, conservo el cambio obtenido en el #2

En la imagen adjunta, se muestra el email en estado inactivo y el nombre, con el campo activado.

Me parece que se logra con javascript. Alguna ayuda por favor?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.inputWithIcon {
      position: relative;
    }

    .inputWithIcon i {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      top: 8px;
      padding: 9px 8px;
      color: #aaa;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    .inputWithIcon span {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      top: -15px;
      padding: 9px 8px;
      color: #aaa;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .inputWithIcon span {
        margin-left: 25px;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #aaa;
    }

    .inputWithIcon .none {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div id="Id1" class="col-12 inputWithIcon">
    <span class="none">Correo electrónico *</span>
    <input type="email" id="email-pro" name="email" value="" placeholder="  Correo electrónico *" required>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-sm " aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

**Alguien puede ayudarme por favor?**

Comment: ¿Usas alguna librería? ¿Revisaste si dicha librería tiene funciones para hacer lo que quieres, como cambiar colores o aspectos de campos con el foco o cuando pierden el foco? Si usas una librería es mejor aprovechar al máximo las posibilidades que ésta ofrece.

Comment: Hace diez años uno hacía manualmente estas cosas. Actualmente existen vaaaarias librerías para que no reinventemos la rueda, como Angular, Bootstrap,... y bueh, React. Te ayudan incluso a manejar los estilos fácilmente. Prueba alguna, revisa si cubre tus necesidades y pregunta por acá cuando encuentres algo ahí que no logres resolver.

Comment: Hola, solo uso el cdn de bootstrap 4.5. Me sepongo ya viene con javascript, pero ahi estoy aplazado. No sé como hacerlo con javascript. Pero con Boostrapt, lo no logro lo que busco, que es la secuencia indicada.

Comment: @MarioCamposS., el fragmento `<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-sm " aria-hidden="true"></i>` está utilizando [Font Asesome](https://fontawesome.com/). También puede conseguir su [CDN aquí](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/)

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano  muy oportuna tu pregunta. La librería que está utilizando por lo que acabo de leer es Font Awesome. Es una librería que utiliza un pack de iconos, a la vez, que tiene incorporado JavaScript.

Comment: Estimados, cargando de forma correcta los archivos del cdn de font-awesome, aún así la lógica que busco no funciona. Por lo que las 2 preguntas del millón de dólares son:
1.- Como cambiar la clase none dentro del span, con javascript? Para que se muestre al hacer clic al elemento.
2.- Cómo cambiar el color del ícono fa, que está e un <i>, al hacer clic en el mismo elemento input?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que el input se muestre en el color que quieras cuando s eproduzca un evento
focus o blur con CSS.

```
por ejemplo utilizando el id del input
#email-pro:focus { 
   border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

puedes utilizar el siguiente código de Javascript para cambiar el color del span.

```
<script src="ping.js" type="text/javascript">
 if ( document.getElementById("email-pro").style.BorderColor = "blue" ) {
  document.getElementById("SpanId").style.color = "blue";
```

}